# Dagger2 compilation error : cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am developing an Android app ans using dagger2 to resolve dependancies but got a compilation error.

Please find below my architecture :

Android module dependencies :

[image]

and my dagger2 configuration :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
  fun presenterComponentBuilder(): PresenterBuilder.Builder
  fun useCaseComponentBuilder(): UseCaseComponent.Builder
  fun authenticationComponentBuilder(): AuthenticationComponent.Builder
```

**then a first subcomponent**

```
@PresenterScope
@Subcomponent()
interface PresenterComponent {
  @Subcomponent.Builder
  interface Builder {
    fun build(): PresenterComponent
  }

  fun inject(signUpViewModel: SignUpViewModel) //compilation error
}
```

**Another subcomponent :**

```
@UseCaseScope
@Subcomponent(modules = [AuthenticationUseCaseModule::class])
interface UseCaseComponent
{
  @Subcomponent.Builder
  interface Builder {
    fun requestAuthenticationUseCasemodule(module: AuthenticationUseCaseModule): Builder
    fun build(): UseCaseComponent
```

}

**with its Module**

```
@Module(subcomponent = [AuthenticationComponent::class])
class AuthenticationUseCaseModule{
  @UseCaseScope
  @Provides
  fun provideRequestSignUpUseCase(authenticationService: AuthenticationService)= RequestSignUpUseCase(authenticationService)
```

**And the last component**

```
@AuthenticationScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {AuthenticationModule.class})
public interface AuthenticationComponent {    
  @Subcomponent.Builder
  interface Builder {
    Builder authenticationModule(final AuthenticationModule authenticationModule);    
    AuthenticationComponent build();
  }
}
```

with its module

```
@Module
public class AuthenticationModule {
  @Provides
  @AuthenticationScope
  public AuthenticationService provideAmazonCognito(final Context context){return AmazonCognito(context);
}
```

***When I try to compile my code, I get a :***

```
PresenterComponent.inject(SignUpViewModel) AuthenticationService cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface ApplicationComponent {
                ^
      AuthenticationService is injected at
          RequestSignUpUseCase.<init>(arg0)
      RequestSignUpUseCase is injected at
      SignUpViewModel.requestSignUpUseCase
      SignUpViewModel is injected at
      PresenterComponent.inject(arg0)
```

Anyone can help me fix this issue please?

Please notice I am mixing kotlin and java. I don't know if it matters

Comment: To allow access to `AuthenticationService` you need to add `AuthenticationService authService()` in `AuthenticationComponent`

Comment: I think I tried your solution but still got the same error

Comment: If AuthenticationSubcomponent is supposed to depend on UsecaseSubcomponent, then it should be the subcomponent of UsecaseSubcomponent, and not of AppComponent directly. BTW this is not really a good module structure, consider using feature modules instead.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it's UsecaseSubcomponent which depends of AuthenticationSubcomponent. But can you explain your last sentence please?  "BTW this is not really a good module structure, consider using feature modules instead"

Comment: I am not as good at describing this as Martin Fowler, so check out https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PresentationDomainDataLayering.html

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i noticed the line making hte compile error is : 
fun presenterComponentBuilder(): PresenterBuilder.Builder